# Will the hashmap.get method iterate over all object values itself?

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I've Googled this but couldn't find a satisfying answer. 
Right now, I got an object containing several values like this (that are taken from a database):

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String vorname;
    private int matrikelnummer;
    private String studiengang;
    private int author_id;
    private int grp;

    public Student(int mat, int tut_id, int author, String stud) {
        setMatrikel(mat);
        setGrp(tut_id);
        setAuthor_id(author);
        setStudiengang(stud);
    }
}
```

An Array of those objects was created but I need to access the objects again for further database related work, so I thought about using a hashmap (for the first time). Either I create one hashmap for each value or I use the already created object with the array slot as key BUT if I use hashmap.get(someMatnumber), will the hashmap iterate by itself over all the objects and the values contained or do I have to add some extra code?

Thanks for reading. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is difficult to understand.  However, this part can be answered if we take it out of context (somewhat):

> if I use hashmap.get(someMatnumber), will the hashmap iterate by itself over all the objects and the values contained or do I have to add some extra code?

If you are asking if the `HashMap.get` method **internally** iterates over all objects, then the answer is "No".  If we assume non-pathological keys<sup>1</sup>, then a `get` call will look at a very small number of entry objects (key / value pairs).  In technical terms, it is `O(1)`.

If you are asking if you can use (just) `HashMap.get` calls to iterate over the keys, or values, or key-value pairs in a `HashMap`, without writing more code, then the answer is "No".

- If you could enumerate all of the possible keys (e.g. you had a separate list of the *possible*) you could this:

  ```
  for (possibleKey K : allPossibleKeys) {
      V value = map.get(possibleKey);
      if (value != null) {
           // we now know that possibleKey is present in the map
      }
  }
  ```

  But that is 1) writing extra code, and 2) probably inefficient.
- The normal (efficient) way to iterate over the keys in a map is to use the key set:

  ```
  for (key K : map.keySet()) {
      ...
  }
  ```

  Note that we are NOT using `get` here at all to iterate the keys.  You can iterate the value set and the entry set in the same way.

---

<sup>1 - There are a couple of pathological situations.  1) If most / all keys in the map have the same hash value, then a single `get` call may need to look most / all keys in the worst case.  2) If a hash map gets really big (more that 2^31 entries) then the map can no longer expand the hash array, and hash chains will start to grow.  However, the average chain length is likely to be roughly `ceiling(size / 2^31))` which only gets problematic if size is gets *really* big.</sup>

Comment: The idea was to have a hashmap like this: Hashmap <Student, int> allData = new HashMap<Student, int>(); then just ask for one of the possible values stored in the student object and get the position of it in the Student[] array. Right now, I guess I won't be using it like that then. Other question: What if I have another hashmap<int, int> and fill in values like this xxx.put(120,120) - would it work?

Comment: 1) To do that you would need to write code that iterates the keyset and tests each one.  Not efficient.  But it is a simple solution. 2) If the other index is acting as an "index" (in the database sense) for the values of some field of `Student` ... that is efficient for lookups.  But it is lots more code, and it increases the cost and complexity of updates to your "database".

Comment: You seem to be looking for a simple Java SE class that allows you to do fast (O(1)) lookup on any of the fields of your `Student` objects.  There isn't one.  You have to build it up from the building blocks, and it is not a simple task.

Comment: Great answer to a not-so-great question.

Answer (score 1):

just do `Map<String, Student> mydata = new HashMap<String, Student>();` and to retrieve your `Student` class do `mydata.get("student name you entered");` and that will return the Student object

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like to thing `.get(#)` will remove the item it is getting.  It does not.  To loop or iterate through a HashMap simply do:

```
for(HashMapKeyType var : hashmap.keyset()){
  hashmap.get(var); //Get the value from hash map using the var.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A map models the mathematical function abstraction. The hashmap implementation makes no guarantees in the order of the map and provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put)